# php facebook payment subscription

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, subscribe

I am trying to implement facebook payment subscription for my app.

I need some help with verifying if userX is subscribed, each time he accesses the application's main page.

Is there a way to call the facebook API using PHP with the PRODUCTID (ID of the selected subscription method), APPID, USERID and then have facebook API return the subscription status?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Create a new app or use existing app**

**Refer this link** : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/tutorial#server-side

**Use GET api** : https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/payment.subscriptions

You will get the json with lots of data in response. Use conditional logic with **"status"** parameter as per your requirement.

**status : [active, canceled]**

I hope it will be helpful for you.
Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the following: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/tutorial#server-side. I hope that helps.